# Moving MySQL to another server without updating connection strings

Tags: mysql

Currently, I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server which runs both all my websites and all my MySQL databases.  I am considering moving MySQL to another seperate server which may also be Windows or may be Linux.  My question is, if I do this, and MySQL is then on a different IP address, is there anyway of aliasing the IP address of the new MySQL server from the current server hosting the websites so I do not have to go through and update every single connection string?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your connection string look like now?

Comment: I have changed the database, userid and password but from my web.config:-

<connectionStrings>
 <add name="Conn" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=MYDB;Uid=MYUID;Pwd=MYPWD;pooling=false;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>


And for some of the Classic ASP sites:-
Const global_database_connection_string = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=MYDB; UID=MYUSERID; PWD=MYPWD;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that the database server ip/name is put in some config file and that all connection strings reference this variable. If both machines are on the same network then use some local name (e.g. mysql.network.local). Then if the machine will change again you will just update your hosts file or update dns records.

Both cases require that every connection string will need to be changed - but it seems inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "localhost" in connection string then the following may work:

edit hosts file and change the line

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

to

```
X.X.X.X localhost //( your new ip)
```

and restart the local application machine.

Comment: Wow... famous last words: "What could possibly go wrong?"

Comment: Am I sensing some doubt with Riad's suggestion?  I have not tried yet as am waiting for more feedback in this post.  It is not something I have had to look at doing before and as my server has many websites on, I just wondered if a method to alias the connection to the new mysql server would be possible.  If I have to go through and update all connection strings then I will have to.